# The default value of an optional parameter must be constant in a constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple class like this:

```
class Staff {
  final String name;
  final String id;

  Staff({this.name, this.id});
}
```

Then following a [tutorial article on applying BLoC](https://codeclusive.io/blog/introduction-to-flutter-bloc/), I put it in `State class`, like this:

```dart
class SignInState {
  final String href;
  final Staff staff;

  SignInState({this.href = '', this.staff= Staff(name:'', id:'')});
}
```

But in `this.staff= Staff(name: '', id: '')`, I keep getting error:

```
The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.
```

`final Staff staff = Staff(name: '', id: '')` works.

Why doesn't it work on that line and produces an error instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the default value for the staff parameter is not a `compile-time constant` because it involves the instantiation of a new Staff object using constructor arguments (name and id) that are not constants.

You can use a non-optional constructor parameter with a default value:

```dart
class Staff {
  Staff({this.name = '', this.id = ''});

  final String name;
  final String id;
}

class SignInState {
  SignInState({this.href = '', Staff? staff}) : this.staff = staff ?? Staff();

  final String href;
  final Staff staff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a constant constructor for `Staff`

```
class Staff {
  final String name;
  final String id;

  const Staff({this.name, this.id});
}
```

Then you can use const for `SignInState`

```
class SignInState {
  final String href;
  final Staff staff;

  const SignInState({this.href = '', this.staff = const Staff(name: '', id: '')});
}
```